# At a nuclear plant the average temperature is $20$ºC. A reation happens and the temperature increases 5 times per hour. When will it reach $2000$ºC?

Tags: calculus

> The temperature at a nuclear plant is 20ºC. A reaction happens and it
>   starts heating so that it is five times as hot per hour. If the
>   reaction isn't stopped, it will explode when it reaches 2000ºC.
>
> Supposing the temperatures follows an exponential model, how long will
>   it take until it explodes?

According to my book the solution is to use the following model:

$$f(t)=20(1+4)^t$$

Then the value it gives for $t$ where $f(t)=2000$ is around 2 hours and 51 minutes.

I have two problems with this:

1. Is the model I used the most appropriate one for this situation? Shouldn't it be a model like $ae^{kt}$?
2. I tried using the model mentioned above and I got $20e^{5t}$, which gives me a different value. What went wrong?

Comment: It seems odd to write  $20(1+4)^t$ when you could write $20\times5^t$. Any reason?

Comment: @Guy Yeah I know they are equivalent, it's just that the formula is $a(1+r)^t$. With $(1+r)=(1+4)$ this means that each value is the previous one plus 4 times that value, or 100% + 400%. It's just easier to understand for me that way.

Comment: For your first question, $f(t)=20\cdot5^t=ae^{kt}$, where $a=20$ and $k=\log(5)$.

Comment: Ah, okay.So, as for your first question, $ae^{kt}$ is the same as $20\times5^t$ with $a=20$ and $k=\log(5)$. You could use the that and use the two intial conditions you know to figure out those values of $a$ and $k$

Comment: @Aweygan But shouldn't k be the ratio? Or unlike with the formula in the solution, finding k is just not so straightforward?

Comment: exponentiation just means "raising to a power".  Using $e$, the base of the natural logarithm, is one way to do it, but $5^t$ is exponentiation too.  The wording of your question is that the temperature increases 5-fold per hour, so that would suggest a model like $Ar^t$.

Comment: The initial temperture is $20$. After one hour you have $20\times 5$, after one more you have $20\times5^2$. See a pattern?

Comment: @Guy Yes, I understand the model. What is confusing me is that I learnt that the model $ae^{kt}$ is used for more scientific stuff like this and the model $a(1+r)^t$ is used for more discrete stuff, like interest and finances. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Guy Wait, do these 2 models represent the exact same thing?

Comment: @MarkRead Those models are exactly the same with $k=\log(1+r)$

Comment: @Guy So the context doesn't really matter, I can just use either one?

Comment: @MarkRead Yes, provided whatever it is that you're modelling "doubles" or increases x times, over a fixed time interval. Such growth is called exponential growth. Actually, even if it halves or decreases by a fixed fraction over fixed intervals of time, it is modelled exponentially. It is called exponential decay, but the equation is exactly the same.(with a negative value for $k$)

Comment: @Guy Alright, thanks.

Comment: @MarkRead as an interesting side note: Since you said that $a(1+r)^t$ is used to calculate interests, the first known use of $e$ in history is by a guy trying to calculate interest.

Comment: @Guy Interesting.

Comment: Fine as a little maths exercise but implausible physics. 100C is only 5 times as hot as 20C using the arbitrary definition of 0C.  20C is 68F and 100C is 212F so the same state in Fahrenheit is only just over 3 times hotter.  It would make more sense in Kelvin as 0K does have a physical significance.

Answer (score 1):

$$20^{\circ}\cdot5^t=2000^{\circ}$$ or
$$t=\log_5100$$

Answer (score 0):

> A reaction happens and it starts heating so that it is five times as
>   hot per hour.

Not showing the physical units, I would translate this as
$$
T(t + 1) = 5 T(t)
$$
which, as we only hit integer arguments, write as sequence
$$
T_{t+1} = 5 T_t \quad (*)
$$
so this looks like a homogeneous linear recurrence relation:
$$
T_0 = 20\\
T_t = 5 T_{t-1}
$$
where we can use [the usual algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients).

The characteristic polynomial is
$$
p(t) = t - 5
$$
with root $r = 5$. Which gives the general solution
$$
T_n = k_1 5^n
$$
and
$$
T_0 = k_1 = 20
$$
so we get
$$
T_t = 20 \cdot 5^t \quad (**)
$$

> If the reaction isn't stopped, it will explode when it reaches
>   2000ºC.

To find out when it reaches $T=2000$ we solve
$$
2000 = 20 \cdot 5^t \iff \\
100 = 5^t \iff \\
\ln(100) = t \ln(5) \Rightarrow \\
t = \ln(100) / \ln(5) = 2.86135\dotsb
$$
where you would need to translate the fraction part of the hours into minutes.
$$
0.86135 \cdot 60 = 51.681\dotsb
$$
so it is 51 minutes. And for the seconds
$$
0.681 \cdot 60 = 40.86
$$
which gives about $41$ seconds.

> I tried using the model mentioned above and I got $20e^{5t}$, which gives
>   me a different value. What went wrong?

You should try equation $(**)$ which you get, if you add $4$ and $1$ in your initial model.

> Is the model I used the most appropriate one for this situation? Shouldn't it be a model like $ae^{kt}$?

That depends on the underlying equation and time model. The book model is a solution to the time-discrete equation $(*)$.

For example having some linear differential growth or loss
$$
dI = C I(t) dt 
$$
in continuous variable $I$ and $t$ will lead to a differential equation
$$
\frac{dI}{dt} = C I(t)
$$
where the exponential function shows up in the solution.